# add labels to stacked bar chart with proportions using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to include labels to a stacked bar chart for proportions.  I have been able to create the chart but I haven't been able to successfully add the labels.  I've gotten labels but they are centered and overwriting one another....I know this has been asked, but I haven't found a solution that works.

The data is tidy in the sense that it is long

[image]

[image]

```
ggplot(data=dat) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", 
           mapping = aes(x=Vintage, y=OrigAmt, fill=fct_rev(Grade)),
           position = "fill") + 
  ggtitle("Proportions by Grade") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey", "gray40", "black")) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE, title="Grade")) + 
  scale_y_continuous(name="Proportion",label=percent_format()) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5),
        panel.border = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

Comment: I'd like the labels to be black on the Grade C and white for the Grade A and B as well.  Also, the x axis labels are shifted to the right of the ticks for some reason?  Any idea why that happens?

Comment: You want a text for each bar? If so, check the **geom_text()** function

Comment: yeah - i have tried a number of iterations using that and other things - haven't found a solution that works yet and keep running into a wall (like most of us R newbies.)

Comment: Can you add in the `geom_text()` call you used that was failing?  If they're all on top of each other you may be missing the `position_stack()`, in which case folks can likely point you to a duplicate.  If you have an additional question about text color you should add that to your question (or likely ask a new question :) ).

Comment: This is one of the frustrating things about R - I assume it’s very simple but I just can’t figure it out without some help.  I want the add labels for each group in each month, so the latest month on the far right would have approx. 66.5% for Grade A, 25.0% for Grade B and and 8.5% for Grade C.  The other months would show their respective proportions...

Comment: I've come to something that is very close - but not I cannot change the label font color to a desired color.  Should I edit my original post to provide an update or ask an entirely new question?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this after `geom_bar`

`geom_text(aes(y = cumsum(OrigAmt)-OrigAmt/2, label = Grade), show.legend = F)`

Changing the y to a cumulative summation (cumsum) of the y variable minus half the y variable places the text in the middle of each section of each bar.
You can also add a color aesthetic and maybe turn Grade into a factor with defined color values

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work.

[image]

```
ggplot(data = dat, 
       aes(y = freq, x = Vintage, fill = fct_rev(Grade))) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(freq,"%")),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 2) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    labels = dollar_format(suffix = "%", prefix = "")) +
  labs(title = "Distribution by Vintage",
       subtitle = "xxx") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Percentage") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", 
        legend.direction = "horizontal",
        legend.title = element_blank()) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = T)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey", "gray40", "brown")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
        axis.text.x.bottom = element_text(vjust = 0.5))
```

However, I want to change the font colors and I can't see to be able to do that successfully.

For example, I want the label fonts to be BOLD and the font for A and B to be WHITE and the font for C to be BLACK.  Thanks!

[image]